# SwiftUI delete rows from a list

Tags: arrays, swift, list, swiftui, color-picker

[image]

As you can see from the image I have a list of colors, I would like to be able to also give the possibility to delete a color from the `array`.

I tried to add a list and then call the `onDelete` call on `ForEach`, but it's not working well it gives me problems.

Then in addition to this I would like the list to be the size of the contained elements.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 16
    
    @State public var select = 2
    @State public var bgColors: [Color] =
        [
            Color(red: 21.0/255.0, green: 101.0/255.0, blue: 192.0/255.0),
            Color(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 193.0/255.0, blue: 7.0/255.0),
            Color(red: 76.0/255.0, green: 175.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0)
        ]
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @State var isShowPicker: Bool = false
    @State var image: Image? = Image("placeholder")
    
    @State private var url: String = "https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/climaxmite.256.718018.jpg"
    
    init() {
        // Segmented control colors
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(Color.blue)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBackground], for: .selected)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.label], for: .normal)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                VStack(spacing: 12) {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-47, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                            .cornerRadius(cornerRadius, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
                        Text("Select Background")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    Picker(selection: $select, label: Text("Select Background")) {
                        Text("Url").tag(0)
                        Text("Select Image").tag(1)
                        Text("Gradient").tag(2)
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 30, bottom: 0, trailing: 30))
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 3)
                }
            }
            
            if self.select == 0 {
                VStack{
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40, height: 42, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                        TextField("http://", text: $url)
                            .padding(10)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                            .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 20, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Submit")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                            .bold()
                    })
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 20, bottom: 10, trailing: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(cornerRadius)
                }
            }
            
            if self.select == 1 {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.isShowPicker.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                        Text("Import")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                        
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowPicker) {
                    ImagePicker(image: self.$image)
                }
            }
            
            if self.select == 2 {
                VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                    Button(action: {
                        bgColors.append(Color.clear)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 20, bottom: 10, trailing: 15))
                    }
                    
                    List {
                        
                        ForEach(Array(bgColors.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                            ZStack {
                                ColorPicker("Set the background color", selection: $bgColors[index])
                            }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 20, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
                        }                .onDelete(perform: delete)
                    }.background(Color.blue)
                    
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 25)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        bgColors.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct RoundedCorner: Shape {
    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}

// extension for keyboard to dismiss
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var image: Image?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        
        @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
        @Binding var image: Image?
        
        init(presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            _presentationMode = presentationMode
            _image = image
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            presentationMode.dismiss()
            
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            presentationMode.dismiss()
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentationMode: presentationMode, image: $image)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Saying "it's not working well it gives me problems" isn't clear what the problem is. Is an item not being removed from the `bgColors` array? Is the view not updating?

Comment: Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444

Comment: First advice is that not every variable in your view needs to be a State, like the url, its never changed. 
Also, It would be good if you could reduce your program code so that the focus is on the problem.

Comment: @Paul What is line 444? Is it `ColorPicker("Set the background color", selection: $bgColors[index])`?

Comment: @mamaessen: Many times they ask me for the complete code to test it, however the interested part is only where it is if self.select == 2 {

Comment: @George_E: I don't have this line, this is the error I get when I try to delete an element, what I think is wrong I assume is: `func delete (at offsets: IndexSet) { bgColors.remove (atOffsets: offsets) }`

Comment: Add a print of `offsets`(or set a breakpoint and debug) in your `delete` function, maybe it doesn't work as expected when using `enumerated()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your `List`, the `id` you give it is `\.offset`. However, since you are removing data from `bgColors`, so this data can change. Instead, you should set the `id` as `\.element` because it will be constant for each color.

Consider this simplified example, which crashes when you remove a `Color` from the list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var arr: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(arr.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { (index, _) in
                ColorPicker("Color", selection: $arr[index])
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }
    
    private func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        arr.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

And the working example, where the changes are the `id` given to the `List`, and the new `Binding` to the color (note the custom `Binding` for the `selection`):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var arr: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(arr.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (index, _) in
                ColorPicker(
                    "Color",
                    selection: Binding<Color>(
                        get: { arr[index] },
                        set: { arr[index] = $0 }
                    )
                )
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }

    private func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        arr.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you say, when I remove last element of the array it gives me the following error: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: @Paul Didn't notice that when testing, but it is fixed now.

Comment: What changes compared to before?

Comment: You can see by clicking the edit history, but the change is I replaced `$arr[index]` with `Binding<Color>(...)`. It no longer crashes now when you remove the last item

Comment: I was wondering what the difference between before and now, that is, what was the problem?

Comment: @Paul I'll be honest - I don't exactly know why it changed anything - but these _should_ be equivalent. I would love to tell you why they aren't exactly the same, but I don't know... at least it works now! Maybe it is to do with the timings of the `Binding` but it must be something internally different

Comment: Thanks it seems to work, although I still don't quite understand what it changes with first.  PS By chance you answered the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64515941/swift-ui-widget-background-based-on-the-value-passed-image-url-or-gradient-backg tells me  that there is an answer from you but I don't see it.

Comment: @Paul Is it the one I deleted? I hadn’t fully tested it after I posted it and didn’t have time to finish. If it is that one I can un-delete and fully test