# SwiftUI Widget background based on the value passed image url or gradient background

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

[image]

[image]

What I would like to do is give the user the option to choose whether the `widget background` is an image taken from `http` or a `gradient background`.

I currently have the following note structure, but I can't get it to work.

So `typeBg` must have a default value, if not passed it should take the default value.

The values of image and `bgColors` must be optional parameters.

```
struct Note: Identifiable, Codable {
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let image: String?
    let bgColors: [Color?]//[String?]
    let typeBg: String? = "color"
    
    var id = UUID()
}
```

But I only get errors, in the struct Note:

> Type 'Note' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
>
> Type 'Note' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

What I would like to do is:

if `typeBg` of the Struct == `'url'`, then I take as value `image` which is a url.

if `typeBg` of the Struct == `'gradient'`, then I take as value `bgColors` which is an array of Color.

ContentView:

```
SmallWidget(entry: Note(title: "Title", message: "Mex", bgColors: bgColors, typeBg: "gradient"))
```

SmallWidget:

```
struct SmallWidget: View {
    var entry: Note
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    
    func bg() -> AnyView { //<- No work
        switch entry.typeBg {
        case "url":
            return AnyView(NetworkImage(url: URL(string: entry.image))
        case "gradient":
            return AnyView(
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: entry.bgColors),
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom)
            )
        default:
            return AnyView(Color.blue)
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                    Text(entry.title)
                        .font(.title)
                        .bold()
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(
                            color: Color.black,
                            radius: 1.0,
                            x: CGFloat(4),
                            y: CGFloat(4))
                    Text(entry.message)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .shadow(
                            color: Color.black,
                            radius: 1.0,
                            x: CGFloat(4),
                            y: CGFloat(4))
                    
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
            .background(bg)
            //.background(gradient)
            //.background(NetworkImage(url: URL(string: entry.image)))
        }
    }
```

```
struct NetworkImage: View {
    
    public let url: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let url = url, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
               let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                
                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            }
            else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took quite a while to do, because `Color` is not `Codable`, so a custom version had to be made. Here is what I got:

```
struct Note: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case title, message, background
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let background: NoteBackground
}


extension Note {
    
    enum NoteBackground: Codable {
        
        enum NoteBackgroundError: Error {
            case failedToDecode
        }
        
        case url(String)
        case gradient([Color])
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            
            if let url = try? container.decode(String.self) {
                self = .url(url)
                return
            }
            if let gradient = try? container.decode([ColorWrapper].self) {
                self = .gradient(gradient.map(\.color))
                return
            }
            
            throw NoteBackgroundError.failedToDecode
        }
        
        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            
            switch self {
            case let .url(url):
                try container.encode(url)
            case let .gradient(gradient):
                let colors = gradient.map(ColorWrapper.init(color:))
                try container.encode(colors)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make `Color` be `Codable`, it is wrapped in `ColorWrapper`:

```
enum ColorConvert {
    
    struct Components: Codable {
        let red: Double
        let green: Double
        let blue: Double
        let opacity: Double
    }
    
    static func toColor(from components: Components) -> Color {
        Color(
            red: components.red,
            green: components.green,
            blue: components.blue,
            opacity: components.opacity
        )
    }
    
    static func toComponents(from color: Color) -> Components? {
        guard let components = color.cgColor?.components else { return nil }
        guard components.count == 4 else { return nil }
        let converted = components.map(Double.init)
        
        return Components(
            red: converted[0],
            green: converted[1],
            blue: converted[2],
            opacity: converted[3]
        )
    }
}


struct ColorWrapper: Codable {
    
    let color: Color
    
    init(color: Color) {
        self.color = color
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let components = try container.decode(ColorConvert.Components.self)
        color = ColorConvert.toColor(from: components)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        let components = ColorConvert.toComponents(from: color)
        try container.encode(components)
    }
}
```

It can then be used like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let data = Note(title: "Title", message: "Message", background: .url("https://google.com"))
    //let data = Note(title: "Title", message: "Message", background: .gradient([Color(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.2), Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.7, blue: 0.8)]))
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(describing: data))
            .onAppear(perform: test)
    }
    
    private func test() {
        do {
            let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(data)
            print("encoded", encodedData.base64EncodedString())
        
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Note.self, from: encodedData)
            print("decoded", String(describing: decodedData))
        } catch let error {
            fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the `Color` you encode *cannot* be something like `Color.red` - it has to be made from the RGB components like using the `Color(red:green:blue:)` initializer.

For you, you could do something like this to change the background depending on `entry`'s `background`:

```
@ViewBuilder func bg() -> some View {
    switch entry.background {
    case let .url(url):
        NetworkImage(url: URL(string: url))
    case let .gradient(colors):
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: colors),
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom
        )
        
    /// CAN ADD ANOTHER CASE TO `NoteBackground` ENUM FOR SOLID COLOR HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm testing it but I'm not getting it to work properly.

The problems are as follows:
1) The Note background, as you called it background, must be the background of the SmallWidget widget, see code above.
I'm trying to do something like `GeometryReader {geo in ...}.background (entry.background)`, but it doesn't work, it gives me the following error: `Instance method 'background (_: alignment :)' requires that 'Note.NoteBackground 'conform to' View '`.
So how can I use the struct you devised?

Comment: 2) In case the background is a url of an image it escapes me how the image is retrieved inside `NoteBackground`, for example to retrieve the image from http I use `NetworkImage`, you can see above the code.

Comment: @Paul Hopefully the example I added was clear. You don't use the `entry.background` as a `View`, but instead the data for those views. Do what you had before with `GeometryReader { geo in ... }.background(bg)`.

Comment: Thank you seems to work, your opinion on one thing.
As you can see from the image I have a Picker to select where the image is to be taken from.
To avoid having to do this: `if select == 0 {SmallWidget (entry: Note(title: arrayBg[select], message: "\(select)", background: .url(url)))}`
so for all the others.
In your opinion, there is a way to declare such a thing: `array = [.url(url), .url(url), .gradient(bgColors)]`
and then simply do `SmallWidget (entry: Note(title: arrayBg [select], message: "\ (select)", background: array[select]))`