# SwiftUI removing item from Form causes crash

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an array of `Date()`, In my `Form` I can append more dates to the array.

```
 @State private var dates: [Date] = [Date()]
```

But when I try to delete a date, it causes a crash. `Index out of range`. I disable deleting when there is only 1 date left, so that is not the issue as you can't delete at that point.

```
Section(header: Text("Notifications")) {
                ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { date in
                
                    let value = dates.firstIndex(of: date)!
                    
                    DatePicker("\(value + 1)", selection: $dates[value], displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    
                
                }.onDelete(perform: { (offsets) in
                    dates.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
                })
                .deleteDisabled(dates.count <= 1)
                   
                Button(action: {
                    
                    dates.append(Date())
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add Notification")
                }).disabled(dates.count == 10)
            }
```

Why does this crash?

Comment: You initialise the array so it contains one date object from start, my guess is that this is what causes the crash because `offset` is then one off so to speak. Change the declaration to `@State private var dates = [Date]()` unless you really need that first object.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you, unfortunately, it still crashes. It doesn't tell me where the error is tho, it brings me to AppDelegate and says index out of range there.

Comment: @PeterRuppert This seems very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514440/9607863). The part you need to change is the `$dates[value]` to the `Binding` like my example on that answer. It might be beneficial for you to also use `.enumerated()` like in that question, since you require the index.

Comment: @George_E perfect thank you, that worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift ui delete rows from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514060/swift-ui-delete-rows-from-a-list)  (marking as duplicate because it's the same issue)